# android Array used in other methods but is null

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to use an array of objects but when I use the array in other methods within the same class, the array comes up null.

```
Summon[] summonArray;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summonsmenu);

        Summon[] summonArray = new Summon[3]; // initialize array
        for (int i = 0; i < summonArray.length; i++)
            summonArray[i] = new Summon();    // initialize each object in the array
}

public void onClick(View view) {
        //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.summonButton1:
                name.setText(summonArray[1].getName());  
//* this is where I get the null pointer and see that the summonArray[1] is null.*
                refresh(summonArray);
}
```

When I check the summonArray[1] in my onCreate method, it has all the values I want, but when I look at it in the onClick or other methods the debugger shows the value as null.
            break;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your re-declaring your array.

The global one is not used, change your onCreate to do this:

```
 this.summonArray = new Summon[3]; // initialize array
```

Answer (score 1):

By specifying a type of Summon[], you are creating a local variable summonArray, which hides the instance field. Use
summonArray = new Summon[3];
instead of 
Summon[] summonArray = new Summon[3];

Answer (score 0):

You've redeclared summonArray in onCreate().

Change the following:

> Summon[] summonArray = new Summon[3]; // initialize array

to:

> summonArray = new Summon[3]; // initialize array

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your summonArray in onCreate() too. Remove it to look like-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summonsmenu);

        summonArray = new Summon[3]; // initialize array
        for (int i = 0; i < summonArray.length; i++)
            summonArray[i] = new Summon();    // initialize each object in the array
}
```